# LFTP can't download more then 9998 files per folder

Tags: lftp

Now i meet a case, remote server has a folder with more then 20000+ files, I start `lftp` using `mirror -c` to download folder from the remote.

But the result is only 9998 files were downloaded.

1/ Are there any settings i should to config in `/etc/lftp.conf`? Or any params i missed on command line to download the whole files?

2/ The other question is that the result of `cls|wc -l` of that folder is `9998` which is different from the result of `ls -l|wc -l` which is `10000l` , What is the deep reason of this sence?

I tried `wget`, which is also 9998 files downloaded.
But FileZilla can list the whole(27592) files.

Comment: Probably some files have some special symbols in the name or in ownership information. See the result of ls and look for anomalies.

Comment: @lav folder is a wordpress date-based format like 2018/08, what's in it are all images, no sub folder, no symbols.